# Use Value of String Array to name a variable (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, naming

I'm trying to combine results of multiple files into one struct.

Said struct should be named the following name:

```
result.[FileName1].Result1ofFile1
result.[FileName1].Result2ofFile1
result.[FileName2].Result1ofFile2
...
result.[FileNameX].ResultYofFileX
```

I save the file names in an String array. Thus

```
FileName(1) = "abc1"
FileName(2) = "abc2"
and so on
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to make it work.

At the end it should look like this, without the need of typing in the abc-Names myself:

```
result.abc1.Result1ofFile1
result.abc2.Result1ofFile2
```

How can I use the String stored in an array as a variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic struct field names](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

```
>> result = struct;
>> FileName = 'test';
>> result.(FileName) = rand(10);
result = 
  struct with fields:

    test: [10×10 double]
```

Or when using a string array:

```
result = struct; 
for k = 1:numel(FileName)
    result.(FileName(k)) = rand(10);
end
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That solved my problem :D